# Using WGPU-native and C++, i cant get multiple instances of a cube to be rendererd?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Im trying to render 2 red cubes using WGPU-native and C++.

If i try this to render 2 cubes using this order of code: i only get 1 red cube.

though if i put this code and corresponding .END() code inside the view loop i get 2 red flickering cubes?

```
    auto view = registry.view<GLTFModel>();
    auto encoder = _commandEncoder->Begin();
    _renderPass.Begin(encoder, _pipeline3D);
```

```
void Renderer::Render(entt::registry &registry)
{
auto view = registry.view<GLTFModel>();
auto encoder = _commandEncoder->Begin();
_renderPass.Begin(encoder, _pipeline3D);

for (auto entity : view)
{
    auto &model = view.get<GLTFModel>(entity);

    glm::mat4x4 S = glm::scale(glm::mat4x4(1.0), glm::vec3(1.0));
    auto R = glm::rotate(glm::mat4x4(1.0), 90.0f, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    auto T = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0), model.position);
    _perframe.modelMatrix = S * R * T;
    wgpuQueueWriteBuffer(_context.queue, _pipeline3D->GetPerFrameUniformBuffer()->buffer, offsetof(Pipeline3D::PerFrameUniforms, modelMatrix), &_perframe.modelMatrix, sizeof(Pipeline3D::PerFrameUniforms::modelMatrix));

    wgpuRenderPassEncoderSetPipeline(_renderPass.GetRenderPass(), _pipeline3D->GetPipeline());
    wgpuRenderPassEncoderSetBindGroup(_renderPass.GetRenderPass(), 0, _pipeline3D->GetPerFrameBindGroup(), 0, nullptr);

    Pipeline3D::InstanceData data;
    data.pos = glm::vec3{1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    data.rot = glm::vec3{1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    data.scale = 1.0;
    data.texIndex = 1;

    wgpuQueueWriteBuffer(_context.queue, _pipeline3D->GetInstanceBuffer()->buffer, 0, &data, sizeof(Pipeline3D::InstanceData));
    wgpuRenderPassEncoderSetVertexBuffer(_renderPass.GetRenderPass(), 1, _pipeline3D->GetInstanceBuffer()->buffer, 0, sizeof(Pipeline3D::InstanceData) * view.size());

    // Upload the initial value of the uniforms
    m_lightingUniforms.directions = {
        glm::vec4{0.5, -0.9, 0.1, 0.0},
        glm::vec4{0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.0}};
    m_lightingUniforms.colors = {
        glm::vec4{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        glm::vec4{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}};

    wgpuQueueWriteBuffer(_context.queue, static_cast<Pipeline3D *>(_pipeline3D)->lightBuffer->buffer, 0, &m_lightingUniforms, sizeof(Pipeline3D::LightUniform));

    auto mesh = model.meshes[0];

    wgpuQueueWriteBuffer(_context.queue, mesh->buffer->buffer, 0, mesh->_vertexData.data(), mesh->_vertexData.size() * sizeof(VertexAttributes));
    wgpuQueueWriteBuffer(_context.queue, mesh->indicesBuffer->buffer, 0, mesh->_indices.data(), mesh->_indices.size() * sizeof(uint16_t));

    wgpuRenderPassEncoderSetVertexBuffer(_renderPass.GetRenderPass(), 0, mesh->buffer->buffer, 0, mesh->_vertexData.size() * sizeof(VertexAttributes));
    wgpuRenderPassEncoderSetIndexBuffer(_renderPass.GetRenderPass(), mesh->indicesBuffer->buffer, WGPUIndexFormat_Uint16, 0, mesh->_indices.size() * sizeof(uint16_t));

    if (mesh->_indices.size() > 0)
    {
        wgpuRenderPassEncoderDrawIndexed(_renderPass.GetRenderPass(), mesh->_indices.size(), 1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        wgpuRenderPassEncoderDraw(_renderPass.GetRenderPass(), (int)mesh->_vertexData.size(), 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
_renderPass.End();
auto command = _commandEncoder->End(encoder);
wgpuQueueSubmit(_context.queue, 1, &command);
wgpuSwapChainPresent(_context.swapChain);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using dynamic buffers with offsets. I actually did another bindgroup entry with the modelmatrix in it then offset it for the next cube. It works!